# Batch file to add line to CSV file on FTP

Tags: batch-file, ftp

Why doesn't this work? I want to edit/add line to a CSV file stored at an FTP server. This work with networkshare.

```
echo %ordrenr%, %teknikker%, %starttime%, %winupdatestarttime%, %endtime%, >>ftp://username:password@192.168.1.241\data\data.csv
```

Comment: @wOxxOm As you say "upload" I gues there is no way to "edit" the file? So the way i sould do it, Download the file using `ftp` from my ftpserver, then edit on computer using `echo %ordrenr%, %teknikker%, %starttime%, %winupdatestarttime%, %endtime%,    >>c:\data.csv`  and then upload it to the ftp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot redirect a Windows command output to an FTP. Only to a file or a device.

You have to store your line to a temporary local file and then use an FTP client to append the local file to the remote one:

```
@echo off

rem Create a record in a temporary local file
echo %ordrenr%, %teknikker%, %starttime%, %winupdatestarttime%, %endtime%, > line.txt

rem Use ftp to append the line to a file on the FTP server
(
echo open 192.168.1.241
echo user username password
echo append line.txt data/data.csv
echo bye
) | ftp.exe -n

rem Remove temporary file
del line.txt
```